# Android NDK, error: undefined reference to function of .h file

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android.mk

This is my android.mk file but when I Compile this I get this error
[Error while creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFXgY.png)

> My android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libNDK
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SerialPort.c 
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c99
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Error messages should not be posted as images, nor linked to. They should be put in text form in the question itself. Also, I don't see any information in your question about where those missing symbols are supposed to come from? I.e. in which C file or library are their implementations found?